# Xcode this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

I have been searching this question extensively and I did not find an answer.

The problem is "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view"

I have stripped out the code as much as possible, but still this error keeps popping up, driving me crazy!

I have the following someSelector.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface someSelector : UIViewController {
    UIView *view;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *view;

@end
```

This is the relevant bit of the someSelector.m file

```
#import "someSelector.h"

@synthesize view;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
2012-08-30 12:42:51.714 SomeApp[2280:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception    'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x6821350> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
```

I think I have tried about everything there is to try. The Outlets seem to be correct and I have tried reconnecting them a thousand times. I also named the class name for the file's owner to someSelector, so that seems to be in order too...

Please help me, I'm out of idea's now...

Comment: Why are you even declaring `view` as a property? I'm surprised that this isn't raising a build warning - UIViewController already has a property called `view`.

Comment: This is a result of trying everything. I'm very new to this... I removed the view property, and still the error keeps popping up.

Comment: Is that real copy/paste code from `someSelector.m` ? If so, I cannot see there `@implementation someSelector` line.

Comment: This is not a direct copy. I have implemented the someSelector. Sorry for that

Comment: `UIApplication` is not KVC-compliant for the key "view".  Your class is, but you're (probably indirectly) trying to set the value for "view" on the `UIApplication`.  Please add an exception breakpoint for ObjC exceptions and post the stack trace that you see when you hit the breakpoint.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue and for me the solution was to go to `Target -> General -> Main Interface` and then remove the entry there. Leave it completely blank. Worked for me (I'm using PhoneGap here though).

Comment: This was the solution for me

Comment: Sweet fancy Moses, I've been looking all over for this and couldn't find it. Simple fix and suddenly I'm back up and running. Thank you sir.

Comment: It worked for me, only after I opened the .xib file in my PhoneGap project.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the class it's trying to find a `view` in is `UIApplication`.  The most likely cause is that you have a .xib file with the file's owner set to `UIApplication` instead of a `UIViewController` subclass...or you have a file's owner that's legitimately the application class but you've connected a view outlet to it.

Open any .xib files in your project, select File's Owner, and verify its class name in the identity inspector.

Sometimes it's easier to find these by opening the .xib file as source code and doing a text search for "view".

Comment: The error gives a UIApplication but I have given the file's owner the class someSelector. And that is a UIViewController. Really strange... In the source code of the xib file (in the IBClassDescriber) it says <string key="className">someSelector</string>    <string key="superclassName">UIViewController</string>

Comment: Is this the only .xib in your project?  The other way that the wrong thing can get attached to UIApplication is if you set the "Main Interface" field in your target settings to a .xib that **doesn't** have `UIApplication` as the File's Owner.

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with someSelector class xib file, check if it is showing any warning and also Abizem is correct you dont need to declare view as property.

Comment: The xib file gives no warnings. So there are no wrong outlets or anything. Is there a better way of checking if your xib file is correct?